Ranking systems within Anime/Waifu gatcha TCG and mobile card games?
I play a lot of gatcha mobiles. I understand C, UC, R, SR, SSR.
Commons are essentially useless.
Uncommon are useful for a limited time.
Rare is almost the same as UC in usefulness, but usually can become SR.
Super Rare and Superior Super Rare (or whatever that extra S stands for) are top class.
However.
I started getting into physical trading cards and I started to notice UR (Ultra Rare), SP (?) and LP (Limited?) and a few others.
What's the source of these rankings? Are they just to make people feel better about their pulls? I feel like some of these at "higher ranks" are pretty subpar.
And why aren't they just using the "classic" systems (F-S) like a lot of Anime/Manga uses?

I’m voting to close this question because this is not about anime or manga. The question may be a better fit for arqade or board and card games.

Related: What's the meaning behind the rarity item's classified in Anime/manga?

As someone from Arqade, I don't think this would fit there either (you could ask a Meta question if you want to make sure).
